# Question regarding using the natural deduction system

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, formal-proofs, natural-deduction

I have the following:

```
Premise: ((V → ¬W) ∧ (X → Y))
Premise: (¬W → Z)
Premise: (V ∧ X)
         |- (Z ∧Y)
```

The part I want to know is how do I go about separating the second premise ¬W so that it becomes ¬Z or (W → Z)

I have heard of doing double negation (¬¬W → ¬Z) but still unsure how to proceed from here.

Comment: I can't understand what you want. The second premise is $\neg W\to Z$. What do you mean with separate?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Can you perhaps elaborate? It sounds to me like you are trying to rewrite the premise "(¬W → Z)" to become "¬Z or (W → Z)", but this is not possible.

Comment: Hi, sorry if I'm confusing you guys I am only just learning this so I may not have all the correct terminology / logic.
I want to solve to (Z ∧ Y). My ultimate goal is to modify the first premise into  ((V->Z) ∧ (X → Y)) but to do that I was thinking I need (¬Z)? or is there a way to easily go combine the ¬W values of premise 2 into 1?

Comment: The second premise is the one you _can't_ split easily split up into two assumptions. But the other two have a $\land$ at the top, so they can be split. Now you have $V\to \neg W$ and $X\to Y$ and $\neg W\to Z$ and $V$ and $X$. Can you see how you can make $Z$ and $Y$ from those components?

Comment: @KreeDo You can't modify the first premise to include $V\to Z$, but I can see you're going in the right direction. Instead look at Makholm's hint above which is the proper way of pursuing your idea.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I understand splitting V→ ¬W using the process of simplification however I do not understand what rule is used for X → Y

Comment: @KreeDo Regarding your last comment, do you have the rule $\to$-$\text{Elimination}$?

Comment: @KreeDo: What do you want to split $V\to\neg W$ for? When you're doing natural deduction, you generally _don't_ want to split implications apart into other things. You need the implications to stay implications so you can use them with modus ponens! (This is also true for several kinds of formal proofs _besides_ natural deduction, by the way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments, you don't need to split the second premise. Here you can use the conjunction elimination ($X\land Y \vdash X$, $X\land Y \vdash Y$), conjunction introduction ($X,Y\vdash X\land Y$) and modus ponens ($X,X\rightarrow Y\vdash Y$).

If I number you premises :

1. $(V\rightarrow \neg W)\land (X\rightarrow Y)$
2. $\neg W\rightarrow Z$
3. $V\land X$

Now you can apply conjunction elimination on 1. and 3. which gives you

4. $V\rightarrow \neg W$
5. $X\rightarrow Y$
6. $V$
7. $X$

Here you can see that if you use modus ponens on 6., 4. you get $\neg W$. 
This $\neg W$ is on the left of premise 2. So again using modus ponens, you get $Z$.

To get $Y$, you must use modus ponens one last time with 7. and 5.

Conjunction introdution gives you $Z\land Y$.

Here is what I get in Fitch notation :

[image: Natural deduction in Fitch notation]

Comment: thanks for the answer, already got it from the hits above but this is a much nicer and neater way to show it!